Excel formulas - how to grab only cells to the left of a value
I have a table of values like so:



X
Y
Z




100
204
200


202
100
102


260
270
108



I'm using the filter function to search the entire table for a searched value.
So if I put in the search cell "100", the filter function should grab the first two rows both containing 100.
My issue is if the search value starts with a "1", i.e. is a 100-level, then I don't want to grab any of the values to the right of that.
So if I search "100", I would like to be return the following:



X
Y
Z




100




202
100




Is there some kind of function in Excel for that?

Index/Match would probably be a good start, although i'm not quite following how 202 made the output based on how you described it? Xlookup may also work if I'm understanding properly

202 made it because I don't want to grab any values to the right of the search value. I DO want to include the values to the left of the search value. So basically my search value is kind of like a limiter - if I'm searching a 100-level item in the array, I would like that searched value to be the last thing that pops up in that row of values. Hope that makes sense @MarkS.

Makes more sense that way, xlookup may not be the way for that then. I'll have to think about it. Are there any other constraints such as not being able to use helper columns?

I think helper columns should be fine; this is for internal use so I can hide columns as necessary.

I posted an answer that hopefully addresses your problem.

I would use a helper column to identify the column that matches your search, and then use an index in the table you want to populate validating against it.
In the image, I have your table on the top and the helper column beside it (formula text is for the first instance of both the helper column and bottom table)
The match says where the column is, the index looks for that column or to the left and pulls the value otherwise it shows blank. If there's no match it shows an error which we also blank out.
=MATCH($F$8,A2:C2,0)
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMN()<=$D2,INDEX($A2:$C2,1,COLUMN()),""),"")
iferror is meant to blank out the non-matches, IF is checking the column of the cell the formula is in (you may have to adjust this so it matches, for example if your table is 4 columns over you would subtract the amount so it lines up with the first column). Index looks at the column we got a match for and pulls the value. Take special note of how I locked the cells as well. You could nest the match function in place of the $D2 if you prefer it that way, this just serves as a sanity check so you can easily see how it works.


Is there a way to have this work similar to/with the filter function? So with this  example I didn't show my entire array of 400 rows of data. If I did this method with a huge array, I'd have to scroll down to see which instances got pulled, correct? How do I eliminate the rows that didn't contain the searched value so the results get shown together?

I have to think about it in that context for a moment. You could filter the rows off the helper column where it is not equal to an error, but i need to think about how to blank out the cells you don't want included

Ohkay I think I cracked it. So what I did was employ your method as a second step. First I did the filter function that gathers all rows with my search criteria into a separate spot. Then I added a helper column to this second table, and made a third table with your method using the "iferror" function to clean it up. Now all I have to do is just hide the second table I made with the helper column and I should have exactly what I need! Just wanted to let you know what I ended up doing.

Here is one way of doing this without using any helper columns:


• Formula used in cell E2
=IFERROR(A2:XLOOKUP(1,N(A2:C2=100),A2:C2),"")



To explain, using XLOOKUP() return all those rows where it matches with 100
Next anchor the first starting cell with the XLOOKUP() so it creates a reference range,
Note that the one which doesn't have 100 in the row will return an error value, therefore wrap the above return using IFERROR() to get the desired output finally
The above formula needs to be filled down!


